# JavaScript Dynamically created object undefined

Tags: javascript, caesar-cipher

I am doing the freecodecamp algorithmic challenge "Caesars Cipher". I have a problem with my code. I try to generate a lookup table as a dynamic object and for some reason it doesn't register. When doing console.log it is says "lookup table is undefined". It is the same with the Acode variable. If I comment out the console.logs then it will work but it will not encrypt anything because of the below part which checks if the char from strArr exists in the lookupTable, if not, it should assign the same value to the encryptedArr (this was done to not encrypt commas, spaces etc):

```
strArr.forEach(function(thisArg) {
    var newValue;

    if(lookupTable[thisArg] !== undefined ) {
      newValue = lookupTable[thisArg];
    } else {
      newValue = thisArg;
    }

    encryptedArr.push(newValue);

});
```

Ofcourse lookupTable[thisArg] is always undefined.
Here is the whole function with the above part as well:

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!

  var strArr;
  var encryptedArr = [];
  var Acode;
  var lookupTable = {}; //this object will contain the mapping of letters
  var encryptedString;

  //check the code of A , this will be a reference for the first letter as the algorith will use Modular Arithmetic
  Acode = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
  console.log(Acode);
  //generate an object containing mappings (I din't want to do it initially but theoreticaly just making lookups in a table would be more efficiant for huge workloads than calculating it every time)
  //this algorithm is a little bit complecated but i don't know how to do modular arithmetic in code properly so I use workarrounds. If a = 101 then I do 101 + the remainder from current letter((Acode + 1) - 13) divided by 26  which works

  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    lookupTable[String.fromCharCode(Acode + i)] = String.fromCharCode(Acode + ((Acode + i) - 13) % 26);
    console.log(lookupTable[String.fromCharCode(Acode + i)]);
  }

  //save the string into the array
  strArr = str.split("");

  //change letters into numbers and save into the code array
  strArr.forEach(function(thisArg) {
    var newValue;

    if (lookupTable[thisArg] !== undefined) {
      newValue = lookupTable[thisArg];
    } else {
      newValue = thisArg;
    }

    encryptedArr.push(newValue);

  });


  encryptedString = encryptedArr.join("");


  return encryptedString;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
console.log(Acode);
```

What am I doing wrong with the lookupTable object creation AND with the below?

```
  Acode = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
```

Comment: `Acode + ((Acode+i) -13) % 26` is wrong. It should be `Acode + ((i + 13) % 26)`

Comment: Did you try `console.log(lookupTable)`?

Comment: Can you try to do `console.log(strArr)` ? It seems that content of that array  might be different than expected.

Comment: @Barmar Yes i did and it says it is undefined

Comment: @user2679265 I am pretty sure this works as supposed because the funtion rot13 returns the same string

Comment: I don't see any way that that can happen. The variable is clearly initialized with `var lookupTable = {};`, and nothing overwrites it. Was your `console.log()` inside the function definition?

Comment: You don't seem to understand variable scope. `Acode` is a local variable in the function, but you have `console.log(Acode);` outside the function.

Comment: @Barmar   //check the code of A , this will be a reference for the first letter as the algorith will use Modular Arithmetic
  Acode = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
  console.log(Acode);

Comment: I ran the code on fiddle and it runs fine no error with lookuptable the acode is not defined because it is out of scope by the time you log it.  acode belongs to your function scope it is not in the global scope.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I put `console.log(lookupTable);` right after the first `for()` loop. It showed an object like `{A: "A", B: "B", ...}`

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I have noticed that I had the Console log outside as well, I forgot I am working on a function and have put it there. So does the code work?

Comment: @Barmar It worked when I did this Acode + ((i + 13) % 26 Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

There's no undefined variable. The problem with your code is in how you calculate the lookup table entries. Your code is mapping every character to itself, not shifting by 13. The correct formula is

```
Acode + ((i + 13) % 26)
```

`Acode` is the ASCII code for the letter, and you shouldn't be including that when performing the modular shift. You just want to apply the modulus to the offset from the beginning of the alphabet after shifting it by 13.

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!

  var strArr;
  var encryptedArr = [];
  var Acode;
  var lookupTable = {}; //this object will contain the mapping of letters
  var encryptedString;

  //check the code of A , this will be a reference for the first letter as the algorith will use Modular Arithmetic
  Acode = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
  // console.log(Acode);
  //generate an object containing mappings (I din't want to do it initially but theoreticaly just making lookups in a table would be more efficiant for huge workloads than calculating it every time)
  //this algorithm is a little bit complecated but i don't know how to do modular arithmetic in code properly so I use workarrounds. If a = 101 then I do 101 + the remainder from current letter((Acode + 1) - 13) divided by 26  which works

  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    lookupTable[String.fromCharCode(Acode + i)] = String.fromCharCode(Acode + ((i + 13) % 26));
    // console.log(lookupTable[String.fromCharCode(Acode + i)]);
  }

  //save the string into the array
  strArr = str.split("");

  //change letters into numbers and save into the code array
  strArr.forEach(function(thisArg) {
    var newValue;

    if (lookupTable[thisArg] !== undefined) {
      newValue = lookupTable[thisArg];
    } else {
      newValue = thisArg;
    }

    encryptedArr.push(newValue);

  });


  encryptedString = encryptedArr.join("");


  return encryptedString;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
var result = rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Still this is weird that it gave undefined errors because it mapped wrong but it mapped to something. Well I got misled by Ceasars Cipher being a subtract 3 letter algortihm. Thank you very much for showing the proper solution:)

Comment: The only `undefined` I saw was from `console.log(Acode)` outside the function, because `Acode` is only defined inside the function.